# Entity cloning and clearing references

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a `Request` entity which has references/children for `Buildings` (many-to-many) and `RequestTimes` (one-to-many). I'm re-using a `Request` object by detaching it from my entity object context.

When I detach my `Request` and go to insert another the `Request` inserts fine with a new ID, new entries are added to my `Buildings` lookup table, but my `RequestTimes` table updates the existing entries and points them at the new `Request` id instead of generating new rows.

So far I've tried using `objContext.Detach()` for each `RequestTime` entry as well as calling `Request.RequestTimes.Clear()`. What else am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Detach()` was required on each `RequestTime` entry. It wasn't being properly called the first time around.